# iOS French keyboard - how to get rid of " spaces around quotes "?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

I use French keyboard as a second layout, for English too. It's nice, but one MAJOR problem drives me nuts - weirdly styled quotes formatting. Look:
[image: French quotes are so French...]

Spaces are added between quotes and words inside of them which looks, at least, excessive. Is there a way to "fix" it? I found no settings related to them, and now every time I type I have to tediously remove the spaces by hands. A stupid business :D

Comment: It’s not clear what the question is here.  But, this may be of some assistance… They are called [guillemets](https://www.ultius.com/glossary/grammar/punctuation/french-quotation-mark.html) and everything I’ve found shows them with spaces.  Is this something you want to fix, a workaround, a solution to removing the spaces…what would you like exactly?

Comment: I don't read French a lot, but in other languages that use them, I don't see the spaces.  But there may be an autocorrect bug—in English, my iPad and iPhone frequently put a space before a closing quote.

Comment: Try turning off smart punctuation if it is on

Comment: @TomGewecke This can work. What is does: when wanting to add quotes with smart punctuation on, it writes « this ». When wanting to add quotes with smart punctuation disabled, it writes "this".

Comment: @Allan I'd simply want it not to add spaces as it does in English layout

Comment: @TomGewecke thanks, it does it! Sadly now those "guillements" are unviable at all :D